# Replicate a railroad diagram using TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to re-create this railroad diagram in latex using tkiz and I am struggling with arrows. I think adding the labels by the arrows should be fairly easy but the challenging part is the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance=5mm,
>=stealth',
black!50,
text=black,
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners},
skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
box/.style={%
    rectangle,
    minimum size=6mm,
    draw=black,
    top color=white, 
    bottom color=red!50!black!20, 
},
rounded/.style={%
    rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    draw=black!50,
    top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
},
start/.style={%
    circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=2pt,fill=white,draw=black!50,
},
end/.style={%
    start,
},
]

\node[start] (start) {};

\node[right=of start] (scc-scheduling-pre) {};

\node[box,right=of scc-scheduling-pre] (scc-scheduling) {SCC Scheduling};
\node[box,below=of scc-scheduling] (chunk-scheduling) {Chunk Scheduling};
\node[box,below=of chunk-scheduling] (group-scheduling) {Group Scheduling};

\node[end,right=of group-scheduling] (end) {};

\graph [use existing nodes] {
(start)->(scc-scheduling-pre);

(scc-scheduling)->(chunk-scheduling);
(chunk-scheduling)->(group-scheduling);
(group-scheduling)->(end);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My attempt so far:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `ext.paths.ortho` Ti*k*Z library and nodes in chain:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains, 
                ext.paths.ortho,  % for -|- path operations
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
   box/.style = {draw, semithick, align=center,
                 minimum height=6mm, text width=9em},
     C/.style = {circle, draw=black!50, semithick, node contents={}},
every join/.style = {arr}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A}]
\coordinate (aux);
\node[box]  {SCC Scheduling};   % A-2
\node[box, join]  {Chunk Scheduling};
\node[box, join]  {Group Scheduling}; % A-4
    \end{scope}
\node (in)  [C, left =of A-2, 
             label=left: Start];
\node (out) [C, right=of A-4,
             label=right:End];
%%%%
\draw[arr]  (in)  -- (A-2);
\draw[arr]  (A-4) -- (out);

\draw[arr]  (A-3.east) -|-[distance=-6em] (aux) 
                node[pos=0.5, right, align=left] {Loop SC\\ for each Chunk}
                        -| ($(in)!0.5!(A-2.west)$); 
\draw[arr]  (A-4.west) -|-[distance=-6em] ($(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.north)$)
                node[pos=0.5, left, align=right] {Loop Chunk\\ for each Group};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```